# Firebase Security & Rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, firebase-console

I have to add a set of rules in Firebase "Security & Rules" but can't find it in the new version. Rules are the following. I am referring to [this manual](https://www.noodl.io/market/product/P201511161733844/social-network-with-firebase-social-network-starter-with-firebase-auth-and-ngcordova) for adding these rules to "Security & Rules" in Firebase. I need some guide as where to add these rules:

```
{
  "rules": {

    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account whose uid must exactly match the key ($uid)
        ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
        // grants read access to any user who is logged in --&& auth.provider === 'password'
        ".read": "auth !== null"
      }
    },

    "usernames": {
      "$userName": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account whose uid must exactly match the key ($uid)
        ".write": "root.child('usernames').child($userName).child('uid').val() == auth.uid || root.child('usernames').child($userName).child('uid').val() == null",
        // grants read access to any user who is logged in --&& auth.provider === 'password'
        ".read": "auth !== null"
      }
    },

    "following": {
      "$uid": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account whose uid must exactly match the key ($uid)
        ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
        // grants read access to any user who is logged in --&& auth.provider === 'password'
        ".read": "auth !== null"
      }
    },

    "followedBy": {
      "$fid": {
        "$uid": {
          // grants write access to the owner of this user account whose uid must exactly match the key ($uid)
          ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
          // grants read access to any user who is logged in --&& auth.provider === 'password'
          ".read": "auth !== null"
        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

All I currently see is:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on Database on the left and there you will have options at the top, click on the rules tab and you will see and be able to edit your rules there.